# [function].apply() causing "JScript object expected" error in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, object-expected

The following line of code causes a "JScript object expected" error in IE:

```
hideElements.apply(window, elements);
```

According to IE, the 'expected JScript object' refers to `hideElements`, which is a function that takes any number of HTML objects as arguments and hide them.

Concretely, I retrieve an array of HTML objects via a call to `getElementsByTagName`, and I would like to pass this array as a list of arguments to the function `hideElements`. The JS function `apply()` is exactly what I need in that case. I know I could surely write my code differently, but since this works perfectly on Firefox and Chrome, and is technically correct, I'd really like to know why IE gets stuck there.

I've determined that, when the line is executed:

- `window` is not null and of type `Window`;
- `elements` is not null and of type `HTMLCollection`; and
- `hideElements` is a fully functional JS function (that works perfectly on its own and that is fully loaded when the code above is executed).

Comment: I don't think IE likes `window` to be treated like an ordinary JS object, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure an HTMLCollection is compatible with an array (it's live), have you tried making a copy into an actual `[]` array first ?

Comment: Thanks Eric, that's where the problem comes from. Unfortunately, converting the collection to an array is not worse doing in my case. I guess my only choice is to use another approach. Makes you wonder why this works fine with FF and Chrome, though... Don't hesitate to post the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: You could also use `call` instead of `apply` and then have your `hideElements` function handle the `elements` collection.  "Calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided individually."

Comment: I simply changed the code to `hideElements(elements)`, and modified the function `hideElements` so that if the first argument is an array, it loops through it; otherwise it loops through the arguments.

Comment: you could also test : `hideElements.apply(window, [elements]);` to see if it's run. (I did this kind of tips in project compatible with old & modern browser)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a `nodeList`. `apply` expects the second argument to be an `array`. If you convert `elements` to a real array (using a loop), it should work.

Note: In IE<9, it's not possible to use `Array.prototype.slice.call(elements)` for that, so a loop is the safest way to create an array, like:

```
function nodeList2Array(nodes){
  var arr = [];
  for (var i=1; i<nodes.length;(i+=1)){
    arr.push(nodes[i]);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

now: `hideElements.apply(window, nodeList2Array(elements));` should work.

Comment: +1. Any specific reason for `(i+=1)` Crockford style or some other reason ?

Comment: @MrBlaster: yep, it's Crockford style. It's a bit clearer what happens to i that way.

Comment: Interesting... i would assume that `arguments` is an acceptable value to pass to `apply`... but that's not an array either... any idea why that's OK, but `NodeList` is not?

Comment: @Dancrumb In IE < 9 `NodeList` is not considered to be a *javascript* object. See http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/06/advanced-javascript-objects-arrays-and-array-like-objects/