# How does JavaScript store DOM elements in variables?

Tags: javascript, dom

What I mean is how does JavaScript store DOM elements when you do something like:

```
var foo = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
```

what does foo become? an array of objects? and how can I add more elements to that variable, for example:

```
var bar = document.form[0].getElementsByTagName('input'); // 5 elements
var foo = document.form[1].getElementsByTagName('input'); // 4 elements

bar =+ foo;

for (i=0;i<bar.length;i++){
console.log(bar.value); // 9 logged values
}
```

Is it possible to add more elements of the same type to a variable that already has elements in it? Do I have to loop trough all elements in the variable I want to add and "push" them in the variable I want all the data in?

Comment: use getElementsByTagName() instead of getElementsByName()

Comment: What would be the difference between using TagName and Name?

Comment: The getElementsByTagName() method accesses all elements with the specified tagname, and getElementsByName() method accesses all elements with the specified name. tagname is html element tag name such as <div> or <p> and name is attribute such as <div name="somename">

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`getElementsByTagName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-A6C9094) (and similar methods such as `getElementsByName`, `getElementsByClassName`, etc) returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) (or [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), depending on the browser apparently, see also [Difference between HTMLCollection, NodeLists, and arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15763358/218196)).

Even though it is an **array-like** object, i.e. it has numeric properties and a `.length` property, you cannot add new elements to it.

In order to modify the `NodeList`, you  have to convert it to a regular array. This can easily be achieved with the array method [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and at the same time you can merge both lists with [`.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
bar = Array.prototype.slice.call(bar).concat(Array.prototype.slice(foo));
```

This works because most native array methods are defined in such a way that the argument does not have to be an actually array, but an array-like object.

The noteworthy differences between a `NodeList` and the final array are:

- The array is not live anymore, i.e. the collection is not automatically updated when new DOM nodes are added.
- The elements in the final (merged) array won't necessarily be in document order.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer, the example, the links for further reference and answering all my questions!

Comment: Hi Felix I thought that you could may be help me with a question that I haven't got any answers only low views. I would greatly apreciate it! [Difference between contentDocument and contentWindow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197084/difference-between-contentdocument-and-contentwindow-javascript-iframe-frame-acc)

Comment: Note that for IE<9 `Array.prototype.slice.call(bar)` does not work it will output the error: "JScript Object Expected" for a workaround loop through all elements in each NodeList and add them to an array a complete example can be found in [[function].apply() causing “JScript object expected” error in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11112950/1079232)

Comment: @SamuelLopez: Try to pass `0` as second argument: `Array.prototype.slice.call(bar, 0)`.

Comment: So IE supports the method but it expects 2 arguments? I found the question above while searching for information on the error and found that example.

Comment: @Samuel: Well, `.slice` usually takes an argument to define the position where the slicing should start. If that value is `undefined` (e.g. when you don't pass an argument) it usually gets converted to `0`. But maybe IE does another check whether an argument is passed or not.

Comment: I tried it as you said, `Array.prototype.slice.call(bar, 0)` but the same error was thrown, for now I'll use the loop since we need to use this small script on IE 8, if you have any more suggestions I'll gladly try them thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> bar =+ foo;

this works only for string concatenation and it would be `bar+= foo`

but both bar and foo here are DOM objects. so if you want to add elements of the same type u can create an array.

e.g.,

```
var myArray =[]
myArray.push(foo);
myArray.push(bar);
```

Comment: Your example would create an array with two values, both of them would be `NodeLists`, not elements. It would not merge both `NodeList`s

Comment: well he mentioned he wanted to add elements to a variable which already had elements to it

Answer (score -4):

foo becomes the function. So you wouldn't be able to add foo to bar because that doesn't make sense. It would be like trying to do:

```
document.form[0].getElementsByName('input') document.form[1].getElementsByName('input');
```

You could have multiple elements in a single array. I'd find that to be the simplest way to reach your solution.

Comment: foo becomes node list not function

Comment: ooo I get it now, is there any way then to store elements in a variable so later you can add more elements to the variable? would using TagName change something like @Givi said?

Comment: @SamuelLopez Felix Kling provided the perfect answer to your question

Comment: @Givi yes he did I just got involved with another task and didn't have time to select it as the response :s I did upvote it though and it is perfect!